# MySQL query to list distinct values?

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble getting a MySQL query to work. I want to query for the most recent entry of each unique 'srcmac' (Source MAC addresses). I can get it to work with LINQ-MSSQL with this

```
    table.Where(g=> g.Srcintf != "port1")
         .GroupBy(p=> p.Srcmac)
         .Select(f=> f.First());
```

here is some sample data

```
itime       ap  srcintf     srcip       srcmac          srcssid user
1558943089      port1       10.x.xx.189                 username
1558943089      port1       10.x.xx.189                 username
1558943089  ARC5    ARCFREE     192.xxx.xx.8    34:ab:xx:xx:e5:94   ARCFREE 
1558943089      port1       10.x.x.13           
1558943089  ARC3    ARCFREE     192.xxx.xx.143  b4:18:xx:xx:fa:d0   ARCFREE 
1558943089  Outside STAFF-RF    172.xxx.x.2 8c:83:xx:xx:85:f0   STAFF   username
1558943089      port1       10.xx.xxx.174                   username
1558943089  Outside PUBLIC-RF   192.xxx.x.32                PUBLIC  
1558943089      port1       10.x.xx.238                 username
1558943089      port1       10.x.xx.28                  username
1558943089      port1       10.x.xx.28                  username
1558943089  ARC5    ARCFREE     192.xx.xx.8 34:ab:xx:xx:e5:94   ARCFREE
```

but am failing to convert it to MySQL.
This is what i have so far

```
    select p1.srcmac, from_itime(p1.itime), p1.srcip, p1.user, p1.srcintf, 
       p1.srcssid
       FROM $log p1
       INNER JOIN
       (
         SELECT max(from_itime(itime)) MaxPostDate, srcmac
         FROM $log
         where ( ( lower(`srcintf`) != lower('port1')))
         GROUP BY srcmac
       ) p2
       ON p1.srcmac = p2.srcmac
          AND from_itime(p1.itime) = p2.MaxPostDate
          WHERE ( ( lower(p1.srcintf) != lower('port1')))
       order by from_itime(p1.itime) desc
```

the dumps i get are

```
srcmac          from_itime      srcip       user    srcintf srcssid
34:ab:37:xx:xx:94   2019-05-28 04:43:29 192.xxx.xx.8        ARCFREE ARCFREE
34:ab:37:xx:xx:94   2019-05-28 04:43:29 192.xxx.xx.8        ARCFREE ARCFREE
34:ab:37:xx:xx:94   2019-05-28 04:43:29 192.xxx.xx.8        ARCFREE ARCFREE
4a:0b:b2:xx:xx:db   2019-05-28 04:43:26 192.xxx.xx.115      ARCFREE ARCFREE
58:d5:6e:xx:xx:c5   2019-05-28 04:43:24 172.xx.x.5  XPUSER  STAFF-R STAFF
```

Comment: Sample data and output would really be helpful here.

Comment: Does the above help @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Problem: The `itime` values are the same everywhere.  How do you break a tie when the times are all the same for a `srcmac` group?

Comment: I see your point. itime isn't the same for every field. Only in this example. This would require a different approach. Something like .First() i just don't know how to perform that in MySQL @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?